# Freelancer.com took my money

Tags: group-freelancing

How can I sue freelancer.com and get my money out of there? I did a project and sent the files to the other user, paid my upfront fees and everything. The guy released the milestone but I cant withdraw because they claim there is an account issue related to the other guy and suggested me to contact him. His account has been suspended so unless they do something about I wont get my money. It's incredible because in the end of the day I paid, spent my time, used my knowledge and took quite sometime and both the Client and Freelancer.com got either the money or the service they hired.

Comment: Hello, and Welcome to Freelancing.SE; unfortunately, questions of this nature are squarely off-topic here, as we're not lawyers, and neither are we freelancer.com's support channel. Consider contacting a lawyer, and reading the terms of service you agreed to.